# Re-allocate space on Centos7 RAID-1 volume from one mount to another

Tags: centos, partition, fdisk

We have a set of Centos7 machines that were configured with 100GB `/tmp` and 400GB `/scratch` partitions. The tools we're using are consuming more `/tmp` space than anticipated so we need to re-allocate some `/scratch` space to `/tmp`.

Our systems are set up with two 1TB NVME drives in RAID-1; relevant lsblk output:

```
nvme0n1              259:0    0 894.3G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1          259:4    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md126              9:126  0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme0n1p2          259:6    0   201M  0 part
│ └─md125              9:125  0   201M  0 raid1 /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p3          259:8    0 893.1G  0 part
  └─md127              9:127  0   893G  0 raid1
    ├─centos-root    253:0    0   200G  0 lvm   /
    ├─centos-swap    253:1    0   256G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─centos-tmp     253:3    0   100G  0 lvm   /tmp
    └─centos-scratch 253:4    0   300G  0 lvm   /scratch
nvme1n1              259:1    0 894.3G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1          259:3    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md126              9:126  0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme1n1p2          259:5    0   201M  0 part
│ └─md125              9:125  0   201M  0 raid1 /boot/efi
└─nvme1n1p3          259:7    0 893.1G  0 part
  └─md127              9:127  0   893G  0 raid1
    ├─centos-root    253:0    0   200G  0 lvm   /
    ├─centos-swap    253:1    0   256G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─centos-tmp     253:3    0   100G  0 lvm   /tmp
    └─centos-scratch 253:4    0   300G  0 lvm   /scratch
```

I am struggling to determine how to shrink the size of `/scratch` by 100GB, and increase the size of `/tmp` by 100GB. `fdisk` cannot find a partition map:

```
[root /tmp]# fdisk /dev/md127
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x6fb1c8c6.

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/md127: 958.8 GB, 958774902784 bytes, 1872607232 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6fb1c8c6

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

I am able to take the machines offline for this procedure, but am unclear on where to start. How would one shrink the size of one volume on a RAID-1 and extend another volume with that space?

Comment: Swap is **waaay too huge**. I really can't imagine any useful swap like that.

Comment: The machine has 2TB of memory, so this seemed reasonable relative to that.

Comment: No, it is not reasonable. It does not depend on the amount of the system RAM. The amount of swap on the *server* is the amount of data that it might swap out, which is rarely used services, like the ones that run once per week and so on. For your case you may measure that by looking how much of that swap is actually used, after long run (a month under typical load is sufficient). Then you should reduce your swap to that number plus some safety margin, like twice that number, around 2 GiB. For example, someone allocated 16 GiB swap on Oracle DB server, of which 0 is used. It doesn't need swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scratch partition is a *logical volume* sitting on top of the RAID array.

You can use a command such as `lvscan` to show these volumes.

Now it's *possible* your volume group has some free space; `vgs` will report on any free space.

So what you need to do is reduce the size of the scratch LV.  If you can do it then a simple(ish) process would be to `umount` the scratch partition.  Then you can `lvremove` it, `lvcreate` a new partition, `mkfs` on that partition, and then `mount` it.

The exact commands will depend on *if* your filesystem is idle; if it can be destroyed; what filesystem type you're using, etc.

Once you've done that then the spare space (`vgs` will show it) can be added to the LV for tmp with `lvextend`, and then finally you can `resizefs` the tmp space.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for me. In my case /scratch contains only temporary files, so losing it was fine. I was able to shrink `scratch` with `umount /scratch`, `lvremove /dev/centos/scratch`, `lvcreate -L 200G -n /dev/centos/scratch`, `mkfs.xfs /dev/centos/scratch`, `mount /scratch`. Then extending `/tmp` was easy: `lvextend --size +100G /dev/centos/tmp` and `xfs_growfs /tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

You have an MD-RAID on top of which logical volumes are configured. **Don't touch the MD-RAID**; instead, shrink the *centos-scratch* volume and extend the *centos-tmp* volume.

Don't forget that you also have to resize the filesystems. Specifically, shrink the *scratch* filesystem before shrinking its volume, and expand the *tmp* filesystem after extending its volume.

XFS filesystems can't be shrunk, as far as I know, but since *scratch* seems to contain temporary data, perhaps it is an option to just recreate it with a smaller size instead of shrinking it. EXT filesystems can be shrunk, but not while mounted. Both filesystem types can be extended while mounted.

The command for resizing logical volumes is *lvresize* (or *lvextend*, or *lvreduce*). It features the **-r** option, which automatically takes care of resizing the filesystem as well. I would therefore recommend using *-r*. However, when shrinking *-r* has the same limitations as outlined above.

Comment: Stephen Harris below adds that *it's possible your volume group has some free space; vgs will report on any free space*. If this is the case, you don't have to reduce the size of the *scratch* filesystem and volume. Just extend *tmp*. Another option might be reducing the size of the *swap* volume, then extend *tmp*.

Comment: Thank you! I marked the other answer as correct because the commands were a bit more explicit, but your guidance helped quite a bit.

Comment: Well done! Let me add that you could have grown the *tmp* volume and the filesystem on it in one command: `lvextend --size +100G --resizefs /dev/centos/tmp`.